# Is there a JSF multi column dataTable?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I need to render a JSF Data Table in a different way: since I have a mid size list of a single column entity, I would like to split it in n different column based on a parameter.

Example: instead of

```
Value1 
Value2 
Value3
Value4 
Value5
```

I would like to have

```
Value1 Value3 Value5
Value2 Value4
```

Is there such a component? In the meanwhile I'll start code it :)

Currently I'm using richfaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`<rich:dataGrid>`](http://richfaces-showcase.appspot.com/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=dataGrid&skin=blueSky) instead of `<rich:dataTable>` (or `<h:dataTable>`).

```
<rich:dataGrid value="#{bean.items}" var="item" columns="#{bean.columns}">
    <h:outputText value="#{item}" />
</rich:dataGrid>
```

If `#{bean.columns}` returns `3`, then it'll render a 3-column data grid.